# Javascript: Objects and properties

Tags: javascript

I have two objects

```
obj1 = {};
obj1[11].id = 123;
obj1[11].lnkid = 111;
...
obj1[99].id = 321;
obj1[99].lnkid = 999;
```

and

```
obj2 = {};
obj2[111].id = 111;
obj2[111].type = 'permit';
...
obj2[999].id = 999;
obj2[999].type = 'deny';
```

How can I get the ID property of object **obj1** or object itself **obj1[i]**, if I need to do these steps:

- I need to compare a value of property **obj2[i].type** (for example: if(**obj2[i].type**=='**permit**'){...})
- If compare success, I get ID of current object (it will be **obj2[i].id** equal to **111**)
- And now I want to find and get object **obj1** which has property **lnkid** equal to **obj2[i].id** (obj1[11].lnkid == 111).

After last step I want to get about this
    var curr_obj = obj1[11];
    var curr_id = curr_obj.id;
    //now curr_id value must be 123

But I don't know how to find and get object **obj1** at last step.

Comment: That code is going to throw a type error because you never defined objects as children of `obj1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go throught obj1 objects and make a compare with the obj2 id?

Like

```
obj2ID = findedID;

var i = -1;
while (++i < obj1.length)
{
  if (obj1[i].lnkid == obj2ID)
  {
     // You get your Obj1
  }
}
```

is That what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`obj[11].id = 123;` is like doing: `obj.<object stored in obj, accessed via key 11>.id = 123;`. Inner object has no type assigned, as no initialization has occured. Apart from that, id and lnkid are object **properties**. Sub-objects are accessed via indexes - key values, for example 11.

I noticed that lnkid-the obj2's sub-objects ids is equal to `obj1Index - 100`, if you follow this convention is convenient to find it easily, doing the following trick:

```
foundObj1 =  obj1[obj2[i].id - 100]; // This has O(1) complexity, very fast.
```

So, if you indeed have a convention on between obj1 indexes and obj2 ids, you can use it for your own good.